# Automapper - Don't map when a source object has a property with a value

Tags: c#, automapper

Our entities have a field called "DateDeleted".   At times we might have these loaded into entities and we want to filter them out before sending them to the client.

Our Entities also have child entities which have child entities, all who have a DateDeleted.

What's the best practice to implement this with Automapper - Specifically - how can I map a Null value to the destination (for the entire object) when the source has a Date Deleted property with a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore a specific property when you configure your mappings

```
CreateMap<srcType, destType>.ForMember(x => x.DateDeleted, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

EDIT:
To do custom conditional logic during the mapping you will need to implement a custom resolver:

```
public class NullCheckResolver : IValueResolver<TSrc, TDest, TProp>
{
    public TProp Resolve(TSrc source, TDest destination, TProp member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (member.DateDeleted == null)
            return member;
        return null;
    }
}

CreateMap<TSrc, TDest>().ForMember(dest => dest.MyOptionalProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<NullCheckResolver>());
```

For more details on custom resolvers, see the [AutoMapper documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers)

Comment: I don't want to ignore the property, I don't want to map the object if the objects property is a certain value

Comment: I see what you are saying, give me a second I'll update my answer

Comment: Why would you want to do this using automapper instead of filtering the result set before mapping?

Comment: @DavidLibido 1. efficiency - if you filter the result set before hand then you loop over the collection once to filter the values and again to do the mapping, whereas with this route you only loop over the collection once.  2. configuration - if you have a lot of different places that need to perform this mapping (say between a Model and a ViewModel on a bunch of different controllers) then you can configure this in one location and it would apply to all places that perform that mapping.  That being said, there is a time and a place for AutoMapper and it needs to be justified.

Comment: The resolver returns an int, but when returning null, would that not just apply Null to the int, rather than tell Automapper to not map this?

Comment: @RyanTernier apologies - I had a typo.  The resolver should return TProp in my example.  TProp should be the object type of the property you want to conditionally return null on

Comment: @Robert Petz 1. I agree if it would be a large collection of objects stored in memory. 2. I don't see the relevance to my comment.

Comment: @DavidLibido it absolutely is relevant because it is a use case for why you would use AutoMapper to keep your code DRY.  For example, let's say you have a bunch of places that map collections of objects from type `Foo` to type `Bar` but they ALL require this exact same custom Null check logic.  With Automapper you define how to map `Foo` to `Bar` once and then everywhere you map between those types it will ensure that logic is performed.  Now let's say you need to tweak that logic - you have *one* location to update instead of every location you actually perform the mapping.